# I deleted Adobe Illustrator, and now Application Manager won't reinstall it

Tags: macos, mac, login, adobe-illustrator

I've had problems with Adobe Illustrator ever since downloading CS6 under the Creative Cloud program. My installation would quit on launch and ask me to license my software, thank me for signing in with a valid license, and loop like that. Yesterday, they hit a breaking point: I couldn't get into the program at all.

So this morning after reading over the forums I saw that an accepted solution was to delete and reinstall the program. I tried it.

Now Illustrator is gone, and yet Application Manager thinks its still there. It won't download a fresh copy. Anybody know a way to get past that?

Comment: Things I've tried so far: Rebooting (of course), Throwing out and reinstalling Application Manager, doing THAT with a fresh boot between the trashing and reinstalling.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with graphic design?

Comment: Obviously, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Found it: I had just thrown Illustrator in the trash, which for every other Mac application, is enough. Adobe needed me to run their official Uninstall Illustrator application. Once I'd done that (with Illustrator already in the trash) Application Manager could see that it was gone

Comment: That was going to be my next question. Adobe is a bit fussy like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Adobe Creative Cloud Cleaner Tool: http://www.adobe.com/support/contact/cscleanertool.html

I had removed the Flash Builder without uninstalling and already cleaned my trash. With this tool I was able to reinstall the app again